# Issue Installing AWS CLI on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I got this error when installing AWS CLI:

> installer: The install failed. (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance. An error occurred while extracting files from the package “AWSCLIV2.pkg”.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the file in ~/Downloads and i moved the file to ~/ and i could install it successfully.

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg" -o "AWSCLIV2.pkg"
sudo installer -pkg AWSCLIV2.pkg -target /
```

Documentation link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Answer (score 0):

I need to move the pkg file into download folder and then install from there. Issue is that I had installer in a google drive location.

Comment: Are you saying that you have solved your problem? Was the problem caused by the location where you had placed the Installer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes. the problem is caused by the location where I had placed the installer

Comment: This was the correct answer for me, I moved `AWSCLIV2.pkg` to `~/Downloads/` and it worked.

`mv AWSCLIV2.pkg ~/Downloads/`

Comment: I got the same error, even in my `~/Downloads` folder. That's when I noticed that the `~/Downloads` folder was included in my `Dropbox` backup. I moved the file to a folder outside of Dropbox, and it worked fine.